# Can I bulk insert to elasticsearch without waiting response?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 7.x. The size of my bulk insert request is about 6MB and `refresh=false`. The response takes about 4 sec. I want the effect like `waitForCompletion=false` on some other RESTful APIs. ES should make response (within ~1 sec) immediately just after it received and validated my request body. Is there any way to achieve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of client language are you using? JS, Java, etc?

Comment: python / rust. I don't use any sdk, simply RESTful API calls.

Comment: Have you tried using [async Python calls](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/async.html)?

Comment: Yes. I can call it async in background, but my program is a web server. I want to know whether ES accepted my request before making response to my caller.

Comment: The _bulk API doesn't provide an async mode out of the box on the REST interface (like `wait_for_completion=false`)